# Woocommerce change sale price with correct product sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

Help me to change product sale price in woocommerce/
I use hooks:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', [$this, 'productGetPrice'], 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', [$this, 'productGetSalePrice'], 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', [$this, 'productGetSalePrice'], 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_date_on_sale_from', [$this, 'productGetSalePriceFrom'], 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_date_on_sale_to', [$this, 'productGetSalePriceTo'], 10, 2);
```

And it works https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkRkU.png. But in woocommerce *wc_product_meta_lookup* tables I see old prices and sorting products is not correct. Should I change meta *_price* for every product which I want to change sale price?

Answer (score 0):

Add codes in your theme/functions.php

In this code: after select sort by price (low to high / high to low), the result of sorting is by sale price.

```
add_filter( 'relevanssi_orderby', 'woocommerce_relevanssi_orderby' );
function woocommerce_relevanssi_orderby( $orderby ) {
    if ( in_array( $orderby, array( 'price', 'price-desc' ), true ) ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        $wp_query->query_vars['meta_key'] = '_sale_price';
    }
    if ( 'date ID' === $orderby ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $orderby = 'post_date';
    }
    if ( 'popularity' === $orderby ) {
        global $wp_query, $rlv_wc_order;
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        $rlv_wc_order = 'desc';
        $wp_query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
    }
    return $orderby;
}

add_filter( 'relevanssi_order', 'woocommerce_relevanssi_order' );
function woocommerce_relevanssi_order( $order ) {
    global $rlv_wc_order;
    if ( $rlv_wc_order ) {
        $order = $rlv_wc_order;
    }
    return $order;
}
```